# Limit products to company assigned to user in multi-company Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, erp, odoo-9

I have a multi-company setup in Odoo, and I would like to limit the products that each user (under the group "User") can access (read/write/create/delete) to the products assigned to the company that the user is assigned to.

To be clear, I have:

Companies:

- Company A
- Company B

Users:

- User A (assigned to "Company A" and user group "User")
- User B (assigned to "Company B" and user group "User")

Products:

- Product A (assigned to "Company A")
- Product B (assigned to "Company B")

With the default setup, User A has access to both Product A and Product B, and I would like user A to have access exclusively to product A, on all modules (Sales, Inventory, POS…)

I believe that is possible to accomplish using Record Rules, but I haven't been able to do it.

Comment: How did you create your companies...is company B a sub-company of A..because by default a user from another company who doesn't have access to company A for example can't see the product of company A...tell us more about your current setup

Comment: @danidee Company B is not a sub-company of A (nor is Company B a sub-company of A), and User B can also see products from Company A. I assigned the company to each user in both "Allowed companies" and "Current Company" under "Edit user", and neither has the "Multi Companies" setting activated. What else could I check?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer I needed from Jerome Guerriat at the the Odoo forums. I only needed to tick a checkbox under the general settings page:

> There already is a product.product multicompany rule (but it is
>   inactive by default): "Product multi-company"
>
> xml id: product.product_comp_rule
>
> You can active it by going to settings => general settings. Check
>   "manage multi company", then uncheck "share product to all companies"

link here: https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/limit-products-to-company-assigned-to-user-in-multi-company-odoo-9-102686

Answer (score 0):

Odoo's record rules are the way to do it, as you mentioned it by yourself. For example look at the rule for sales order (sale.order). It's global (no group selected/assigned) and it's restricted to companies:

`['|',('company_id','=',False),('company_id','child_of',[user.company_id.id])]`

Now create your own record rules for product.template and product.product like the example under Settings/Technical/Security/Record Rules (in Odoo V9 you'll need developer mode to see this) or within a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Odoo Can manage share partner and product without add rules:

1. Use multiple company
2. Don`t forget add parent company at Settings > Users> companies (choose child company)
3. Uncheck Share partner to all companies and Share product to all companies at Settings > General Settings > Shared resources

So, Difference company can`t read product.....